# Create New Record_Start/End dates based on previous record/closest match?

Tags: loops, increment, offset

I'm trying to create a fix for some data errors in one of our tables that has an inconsistent Start/End date format. Some records have a Start Date that matches the End Date of the most recent previous record and some increment by one day, example:

| Record_Start | Record End |

| 5/1/2021     | 5/27/2021  |

| 5/27/2021    | 7/8/2021   |

| 7/9/2021     | 12/31/9999 |

Any thoughts on how to go about that? I was thinking that it would be some sort of loop to look for the max end date that is <= the record start date or a way to offset and just use the end date from the prior record as the start date for the next?

Answer (score 1):

Found the Answer.

,Min(RECORD_END) Over (ORDER BY RECORD_START ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) AS NEW_RECORD_START